# Stretch canvas 100% width but contain in window

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, window-resize

I have a canvas that I am stretching with CSS using `width: 100%;`. It works great to maintain aspect ratio because the height adjusts automatically. But I want it to stop growing when the window is resized so wide that the canvas' height would be below the fold. Is there an easy CSS property-value for this?

I thought the `object-fit` property could do that, but I think I'm not understanding something.

Please also note that I have 2 canvases layered on top of each other, so the solution shouldn't mess with the absolute positioning they have to their 'position: relative;' parent container.

EDIT: Here is a simplified version of my setup. Canvas sizes are initalized with JavaScript, and then the CSS width property  stretches it to the full width of the page. Please be mindful of the  control bar I put at the top because it takes up space as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Canvas Demo</title>
    <style>
        canvas{
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: #eee;
        }
        #controls{ 
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 50px 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    
        function init(){
            let canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas_environment");
            canvas1.width = 1200;
            canvas1.height = 1000;
            let canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas_agents");
            canvas2.width = 1200;
            canvas2.height = 1000;
        }

    </script>
    
</head>

<body onload="init()">

    <!-- Control bar on top -->
    <div id="controls">
        <button>GO</button>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Two canvases overlaid to avoid redrawing the environment every frame -->
    <div style="position: relative;">

        <canvas id="canvas_environment"
            style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;">
        </canvas>
        
        <canvas id="canvas_agents"
          style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;">
        </canvas>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know the aspect ratio in advance? Please provide minimal code which shows your structure and relevant CSS.

Comment: Yes, the width and height are initialized with JavaScript. I added a code example with the relevant parts. I chose 1200x1000 to make it easy to test, but I'd like to know how to do it for any ratio. Thx.

Comment: Do i understood your question correctly that you dont whant to scale the canvas height over the edges of the window? Does adding a max-height: 100% fix this issue?

Btw scaling the canvas with css could affect the render quality of your canvas. So i would suggest a solution without css But thats not the topic of this question. Here is a blogpost related to the scaling topic: https://medium.com/@doomgoober/understanding-html-canvas-scaling-and-sizing-c04925d9a830

Comment: Correct, I want the whole canvas contained in the window. I am aware of the render quality when scaling, but in this case it's not an issue for me.

Comment: @MartinGodzina and no, max-height: 100% doesn't work because it stops it from growing past its original height of 1000px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To account for the button space above the canvases this snippet puts both the button and canvases into a container which is then divided up using grid - so the canvases can take the remaining vertical space.

Each canvas is given max width and height of 100% (which will equate to the width and height of the cell) and then object-fit is used to ensure it adjusts appropriately.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Canvas Demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    canvas {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: cyan;
    }
    
    #controls {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 50px 20px;
    }
    
    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function init() {
      let canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas_environment");
      canvas1.width = 1200;
      canvas1.height = 1000;
      let canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas_agents");
      canvas2.width = 1200;
      canvas2.height = 1000;
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Control bar on top -->
    <div id="controls">
      <button>GO</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Two canvases overlaid to avoid redrawing the environment every frame -->
    <div style="position: relative;">

      <canvas id="canvas_environment" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;">
        </canvas>

      <canvas id="canvas_agents" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;">
        </canvas>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this works... the "max" properties for width and height are preventing the canvas from growing larger than its original dimensions of 1200x1000 pixels. I want it to grow as large as it can until either the width or height hits the edge of the window.